# Stackoverflow careers, overseas?

Tags: discussion, jobs

I just wonder, are the global searches much fewer than US searches currently?

(Assuming I understand correctly what they are.)

Right now it is at 1725 Global Searches.  You people in the US, what do you see?

4 hours later it is at 1727 searches. So not exactly a torrent of searches.

---

Update: Thanks for the answer. I see "Global Searches" is changed to "Total Searches". Excellent.

Comment: I don't think the US searches are listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global searches just means "searches". It does not mean US versus non-US.

More live employer search data is available now for everyone:

[image]

Comment: By the way, when I found your podcast around number 40-50, I first listened to ALL the backlog and has been hooked to every podcast since.  So far I am drinking the KoolAid...

Comment: Anyway, couldn't you leak some info in the next podcast about what "topics" employers search for the most?

Answer (score 2):

You can assume that the careers.so employers are the same as the jobs.joelonsoftware.com
In which case they are 95% USA with a few in London/Cambridge (UK)